# Understanding UINT8 from BLE device with Javascript

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy

I seem to be unable to understand a result back from the Battery Service of a BLE device.  I am using: https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central.

If I stringify the response I get the following:

("0":"57")

Code used:

```
function readBttnBattery() {
    var devid = localStorage.getItem('vBttn');
    ble.read(devid, '180f',
             '2a19', 
             function(t) {
        var data = new Uint8Array(t)
        console.log('button Battery:');
        console.log(' BatLev: ' + JSON.stringify(new Uint8Array(t)));
    }, function(f) {
        console.log(f);
    });
}
```

But when I use another App, and connect to the device, it gives me a graphic resemblance of the Battery Level, and its in the high 90's.  So when my app gives me 57, I am a little confused.

Am I not reading the '57' correctly.  If I decode it like by putting `data` through this:

```
function bytesToString(buffer) {
return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
}
```

If gives me the number '9'.  Should this represent 90 % ??

I am little confused by it, so any help would be massively appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It does seem a little messy, reading up on it some more:

http://www.javascripture.com/Uint8Array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array

It would seem the number coming from my App, 57, is correct, based on my understanding given in here: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicsHome.aspx?_ga=1.1402161.140200314.1452253448

So one would have to assume, the number is incorrect from one of the Apps. I will find another app, see if i can get a 3rd view.

But I would assume 57 = 57%, unless someone else has an idea :)

Thanks

Addy

Comment: Sorry, I am using the plugin https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

Comment: is it representing  57 / 64 ? (that's 89%...)

Comment: @dandavis Hiya, where do you get the 64 from ?

Comment: One common source of confusion is that BLE does everything in binary and so it's likely that the "57" you're seeing is the percentage in hex.  "64" is hex for 100.  However, you can't do 57/64 and treat them as decimal.  "57" is 87 in decimal and it's likely that your battery is at 87%.

Comment: @TimTisdall Thank you Tim, it does make more sense for a new battery to be higher than 57%. So I shall take your example.  Thanks again :)

Comment: @AndrewWalker - well, a fresh battery should probably show as "64" which would be 100%...  87% seems odd for a _new_ battery, but less so than 57%

Comment: The success function should be receiving an array buffer of "raw data from native code". In the success function does  `JSON.stringify(data)` return `{"0":57}` without quotes around 5?. Also does `console.log("data[ 0] = " + data[0])` show the value as 57?

Comment: Hi, yes it does return `{"0":57}`.  Interesting, in the documentation is gives an example of a result being this : "The Battery Service exposes the Battery Level of the coin cell in V.BTTN.
Battery level are reported as a percentage, e.g. 5C is 92%.".   Based on this, I should not get 57, shouldn't 6 be the last digit ?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption not needed

The [bluetooth battery level characteristic](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml)  is an 8 bit unsigned integer between 0 and 100 giving the percentage battery charge. Values between 1 and 255 are "reserved" - as in unused.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I did look at that page, but it still does not make clear how to interpret the number.  Given that i get two different responses.  8 bit integer is a byte, so in my app, the response is  57.  But it does not explain what that number means ?

Comment: In what exact way does a percentage number between 0 and 100 require interpretation?

Comment: Thank you, as I pointed out in my OP, I am getting conflicting results, and as the battery is brand new, it is unlikely, but not impossible, to be 57%.  As Tim commented above, numbers are in Binary, which makes more sense.  However, as its a brand new battery even 89% is a push to think it's correct.  But I do appreciate your time :)